# Get location from multiple devices on demand

Tags: javascript, node.js, location, device

Just to set the background, I'm working on an app with Cordova + Sencha Touch and NodeJS + MongoDB as backend. Now I need to have some devices (tablets or smartphones) send some data to a central device (pc), that would to be done periodically or on demand. I'm trying to figure out what the best way of doing that is.

Just to make myself clear...

```
                   Device 2 <------ Device 0 -----> Device 1
                                       |
                                       |
                                       v
                                    Device 3
```

So with that illustration in mind: I'd need to have Device 1, 2 and 3 (tablet or smartphone) send their current location (along with some other information) to Device 0 (pc, server, etc). Keep in mind that there's actually gonna be a lot more than 3 devices, say 1500 or 2000.

What I thought was have them send that data periodically to a database and then query that database whenever it's needed. That would have to be done once every 30 seconds (or less) though. 
I really have no idea of what the best way of doing this would be though, I suppose I could achieve this by setting a counter on the device's app and having it send the data to the database, but I'm certain there has to be some more efficient way.

The other option is having them send their data on demand, but that seems like more workload as there's a ton other devices (hopefully in the 10s or 100s thousands) that will have to ask those 2k devices for that data, and that could be whenever the user wants to.

So, are there any other ways of doing this that I'm missing?

**EDIT**
Just for the record, I ended up chosing the first option. Just record whatever status I needed on my db and query whenever I need to check for changes.

Comment: What sort of location definition and granularity do you need? I've done something similar (on a smaller numbers scale though, granted) with Google Latitude. This may or may not be suitable depending on context, but there is an API you can pull the data out of and in to a database to do as you need with. As a bonus it only updates when the Device moves.

Comment: Actually I already sorted the way of getting the location from the device and use it locally (on the app). What I'm trying to figure out is the way of the device to send it's location to the other devices. And by the way, those devices are going to be in constant motion.